# How to display result in two column form one column resource with different where

Tags: sql

I try to count record which is on current date and pass date from date column

DATE

```
'2013-03-04 00:00:00'

'2013-02-04 00:00:00'

'2013-02-04 00:00:00'
```

if today is `'2013-03-04 00:00:00'`

the result should be

CURRENT_DATE = 1
PASS_DATE = 2

I Don't know how to query it form one resource but different where condition

```
1st - date >= '2013-03-04 00:00:00'
2nd - date <  '2013-03-04 00:00:00'
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: 1st = where condition of current_date
2nd = where condition of pass_date

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using two sub-queries within a `SELECT` clause

```
select
   (select count(*) from MyDates where DateValue < getdate()) as PastDate,
   (select count(*) from MyDates where DateValue >= getdate()) as CurrentDate
```

You can replace `getDate()` with a date parameter or a hard-coded value such as '2013-03-04' if you wish.

Comment: THANK YOU THAT WAS HELP ME A LOT !! ^_______^

*but i can't click this link is useful so sorry 
(i don't know why)but want to say thank you again

Comment: @JongzPuangput Which link are you having trouble clicking?

Comment: no no i just want to click your answer is useful, now i can clicked ^_^ because my reputation just above 15.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to query for all dates and place 1\0 according to your condition
then just query again from the table an sum the columns.

```
SELECT sum([CURRENT_DATE]), sum([PASS_DATE])
FROM
(
  SELECT 
     ID,
     case when myDate >= getDate() then 1 else 0 end as [CURRENT_DATE],
     case when myDate < getDate() then 1 else 0 end as [PASS_DATE]
  FROM mytable

) as SourcTbl
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9c19/8